# How to get from second view controller to the third view controller through push segue

Tags: ios, swift

Im creating an app for one of my classes, and I've run into a road block. My first view controller features types of restaurants (American, Latin, Italian, etc). You click those, and it goes to the second view controller which displays five restaurant names in my town.

That part works fine. What I want to do next is click on the restaurant name to go to a third view controller to display information on the restaurant clicked like address, description and eventually a map of the location as well.

I'm getting a red stop sign in my prepareForSegue function:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

    // get a reference to the second view controller
    let americanDetailController = segue.destinationViewController as! AmericanDetailViewController

    // set a variable in the second view controller with the String to pass
    americanDetailController.american = American
}
```

The red sign is showing up in the "americanDetailController.american = American line. It's created very similarly to the code from the first view controller to the second, so I'm not sure what I'm missing here.

Comment: How is the `american` property declared in `AmericanDetailViewController`?  Where is `American` declared?  If it is a variable, it should start with a lowercase letter.  What is its type?

Comment: Click on the red stop sign.  What is the error message?

Comment: ^Definitely agree w/ vacawama. Please provide us with the error message that is presented by clicking on the red stop sign. If you are trying to pass a string it shouldn't be uppercase. Class names should be capitalized, while method names and variables should start with a lower case letter. Variables in Swift (along with many other languages) should be in camelCaseFormat.

Comment: It says: Cannot convert value of type '(UnsafePointer<Int8>, Int32) -> UnsafeMutablePointer<Int8>' to expected argument type 'Int'

Comment: It should be connecting to one of data files. I created a struct called American with the information it should be pulling from, which is how the other view controller pulls information.

Comment: show the definition of American.  It looks like it is a function and you're trying to assign it to an Int.

Comment: What does this mean?? --> Cannot convert value of type '(UnsafePointer<Int8>, Int32) -> UnsafeMutablePointer<Int8>' to expected argument type 'Int'

Comment: ^ Would you add the error message into the question?